# Reading file with POSIX read

Tags: c, posix, file-read

I have a file which is dumped by the following code:

```
for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  unsigned char byte = rand() % 16; 
  printf("%02x", byte);
}
```

I can read this file using `fscanf`:

```
uint8_t *buf;
uint64_t index = 0;
unsigned int byte;
while (fscanf(input_file, "%02x", &byte) == 1) {
  buf[index] = static_cast<uint8_t>(byte);
  index++;
}
```

How do I use the POSIX `read` function instead of `fscanf` to read the values into `buf`?

Comment: You still want to have `uint_8` values in `buf` or you just want to read the raw file?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I want to store `uint8_t` value not the raw bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... let me just start by saying that working with raw syscalls is not that simple. You have to take into account a variety of problems and edge cases that normal stdio functions take care for without you even noticing. **Carefully read [the manual page for `read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) before writing the program.**

With the above being said, you can achieve what you want by creating a simple map that maps every ASCII character to its hexadecimal value. In the example below, I use `0x0` to also fill values that are not valid, but you could for example declare it as `int8_t` and fill invalid values with `-1`. That's up to you.

Once you have a map that translates every ASCII character to the given hex value, you can use it to simply lookup the needed values, so for example `hexmap['a'] == hexmap['A'] == 0xA`. You can obtain a single `uint8_t` by reading two hex digits and then combining them with a simple left shift and binary OR, like this:

```
uint8_t value = 0xA << 4 | 0x1;
// Using the map:
uint8_t value = hexmap['a'] << 4 | hexmap['1'];
// value == 0xA1
```

Here's a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

static const uint8_t hexmap[128] = {
    0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
    0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
    0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
    0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
    0x0, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
    0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
    0x0, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
    0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
};

int main(void) {
    uint8_t *buf;
    int fd;

    // Open file.

    fd = open("your_file", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    // Allocate buffer.
    // Make sure it's big enough, or reallocate while reading later.

    buf = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * 10);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed");
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned char digits[2];
    size_t total = 0;
    ssize_t nread;

    while (1) {
        nread = read(fd, digits, 2);

        if (nread == -1) {
            perror("read failed");
            return 1;
        } else if (nread == 0) {
            // EOF reached
            break;
        }

        buf[total] = hexmap[digits[0]] << 4 | hexmap[digits[1]];
        total++;

        // Here be sure to reallocate buf if total gets too high.
    }

    close(fd);

    // Do whatever you want...
    // For example, print the values.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        printf("%d: %hhu\n", i, buf[i]);
    }

    free(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

```
0a01ff
```

Output:

```
0: 10
1: 1
2: 255
```